# What is a "Job" (child process thing) in Windows, and when to use it?

Tags: windows, winapi, process, task

Using [Process Explorer](http://live.sysinternals.com/) ([procexp.exe](http://live.sysinternals.com/procexp.exe)), especially with Google Chrome, child processes are called a Job. Same with Internet Explorer 8, but I noticed it first with Chrome.

1. What is a *Job*
2. What should I *know* about these things?
3. *Why* would (*you*|*one*) use them?
4. What *scenarios* should they be used?
5. What APIs are used.

I know the questions is a bit clumsy, please try and look past that. Thanks in advance.

I'm using WinXP by the way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ad 1/2. A job is a process with a [job object assigned](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684161%28VS.85%29.aspx). They're used to manage groups of processes. One job object can have multiple process, but a process can be assigned to only one job object. You can also set several limits for the jobs, documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686216%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Ad 5. [CreateJobObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682409(VS.85).aspx), [AssignProcessToJobObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681949(VS.85).aspx), [SetInformationJobObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686216%28VS.85%29.aspx), [TerminateJobObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686709(VS.85).aspx), and few more, listed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684847%28VS.85%29.aspx#job_object_functions).

Answer (score 9):

A Job under Process Explorer refers to [Win32 Jobs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684161%28VS.85%29.aspx). More information about this feature can be found [here](http://www.downloadatoz.com/manual/pr/process-explorer/Options.htm).

So,

**1. What is a Job?**
As above.

**2. What should I *know* about these things?**
If a job fails or becomes unstable, all processes it manages will become unstable or crash immediately.

**3. *Why* would (*you|one*) use them?**
They are interesting tools if my application/system fires up several processes. I can centralize certain tasks in one job and attach all processes to it. Like gracefully terminate all processes, manage their working sets, etc.

**4. What *scenarios* should they be used?**
Never did anything worthed using them. But as above. In applications or complex systems that fire up several processes. Under Chrome, for instance (since this is where you are seeing a job), it is quite possible the job is managing each process that is fired when you open a new tab.

**5. What APIs are used?**
The Win32 API